# Location of Pentaho 5 log config

Tags: log4j, pentaho

I'm trying to connect Pentaho 5.4 (kitchen job runs to be precise) to our Logstash Server. To do that, I need to edit the Log4j config file so it will use the new appender.

I searched every jar file and every folder, but to no avail. Pentaho 6 comes with several `log4j.xml` files, but none of them seems to be used for the output, either. Also, the `-Dlog4j.debug` flag does not give me useful any info. Am I barking at the wrong tree?

A typical log looks like this:

`Kitchen.bat -Dlog4j.debug /file "samples\jobs\changelog\Process changelog.kjb"
..
2016/04/14 15:24:17 - Kitchen - Start of run.
2016/04/14 15:24:18 - Process changelog - Start of job execution
..
2016/04/14 15:24:21 - General - Change log processing 2 - Finished processing (I=0, ... E=0)`

Any help is greatly appreciated!